# Word vectors from a whole doc2vec model vs. word vectors from a particular document

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I trained a gensim's Doc2Vec model with default word2vec training (dm=1). I can get the word vectors from the global model in model.wv.vectors.
But the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) says that the same word ("leaves" in the example) won't have the same vector depending of the document context where it appear.

So I'm a bit confused : in the model.wv.vectors, will the word "leaves" by example, have the same vector for all the documents used to train the model (that may be contradictory with what I understand from the documentation) ? If not, how to get the word vectors from a particular document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation is misleading. The word-token `'leaves'` will have only one word-vector in that model.

I'm guessing the author of that comment *may* have meant that during model-training in PV-DM mode (`dm=1`), the training-predictions would be influenced by a combination of the word-vector and the 'floating' doc-vector for that text (and other neighboring word-vectors within the context-window). But still, the one word just has the one vector, and the description there is confused.